# what does [direction] mean here in this snippet

Tags: javascript

I copied a code where the component slides from right or left to center but i don't know how the parameter is used. i dont know of any `[direction]: 0` property in CSS

```js
function slideTo(direction) {
    const optional = {optional : true}
    return [
        query(':enter, :leave', [
            style({
                position: 'absolute',
                top:0,
                [direction]: 0,
                width: '100%'
                
            })
        ], optional),
        query(':enter',[
            style({ [direction]: '-100%' })
        ]),
        group([        
            query(':leave',[
                animate('600ms ease-in-out', style({ [direction]: '100%'}))
            ], optional),
            query(':enter', [
                animate('600ms ease-in-out', style({ [direction]: '0%'}))
        ])
    ])
    ]
```

Here's the whole ts file

```js
import {
    trigger,
    transition,
    style,
    query,
    group,
    animateChild,
    animate,
    keyframes
} from '@angular/animations'

export const slider = 
    trigger('routeAnimations' , [
        transition('* => isRight', slideTo('right') )
    ]);


function slideTo(direction) {
    const optional = {optional : true}
    return [
        query(':enter, :leave', [
            style({
                position: 'absolute',
                top:0,
                [direction]: 0,
                width: '100%'
                
            })
        ], optional),
        query(':enter',[
            style({ [direction]: '-100%' })
        ]),
        group([        
            query(':leave',[
                animate('600ms ease-in-out', style({ [direction]: '100%'}))
            ], optional),
            query(':enter', [
                animate('600ms ease-in-out', style({ [direction]: '0%'}))
        ])
    ])
    ]
}
```

app.component.html

```html
<main [@routeAnimations]="prepareRoute(outlet)" class="content">
    <router-outlet #outlet="outlet"></router-outlet>
</main>
```

app-routing.module.ts

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: 'equipment', component: EquipmentComponent, data: {animation: 'isRight'}},
  {path: '', component: MainformComponent,canActivate:[AuthGuard]}
];
```

Comment: It looks to me like it's setting the base for animation.  Since lower you have the pseudo elements of `enter` and `leave` with animation easing of `0%` and `100%` respectively .. But without the entire code snippet it's hard to say for sure ...

Comment: thanks for the response. just updated the question with the related code

Answer (score 0):

`[direction]` is a variable.  It is dynamic.  Calling `slideTo(margin)` will select `margin` in the style object and set its value.  You might also call `slideTo(right)` for `position: absolute` elements, which is what the author is doing in the `trigger` function.  It depends what you're trying to do.  This is how you can choose key-value pairs in an object without explicitly knowing the name of the key ahead of time.

Comment: Great, so that also explains why he used 'right' as the parameter, he means he's controlling the right property

Answer (score 0):

The function `slideTo` is called in your code snippet as `slideTo('right')`.

```js
export const slider = trigger('routeAnimations' , [
        transition('* => isRight', slideTo('right') )
    ]);
```

Which makes it clear that `slideTo` is meant to be called with the string literal `'right'` or `'left'`.

So if you call `slideTo` with `'left'` it is meant to set the CSS property `left` on the absolute positioned element.
`[direction]: 0` just sets the key name dynamically as `left: 0` or `right: 0` based on the argument passed.